# Why cant I see Java project view in VS Code?

Tags: java, jar, visual-studio-code

So I'm trying to add jar files to a java project.

I've been told the following:

> If you want a more beginner-friendly way of adding libraries, you can
> also use the [Project Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-dependency) for Java extension, which is included in
> the Java Extension Pack. With it, you can click the + icon on
> Referenced Libraries in the JAVA PROJECTS view, as shown in [this
> example](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_add-a-jar). A quick tip if you need to add many libraries from a folder
> is to Shift or Alt + click the + icon, which will let you select an
> entire folder containing multiple .jar files.

After installing Project manager extension and creating a new Java project in VS code, I get to this screen.
[image: My Java project3]

As mentioned by VS code, I should be able to see the project view tab after creating my java project. The issue is I don't see the project view tab as shown in the image above. VS code says I should see the 3 dots by the explorer subheading to enable it, but again, I don't have these 3 dots as shown in the first image.

[image]

I have both project manager and the extension pack installed, so I really don't understand why I cant see or enable project view.

[image]

Any suggestions on enabling project view?

Comment: Looks like you are not using the latest extension since the content of screenshots are out-of-date

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried to open a java file? Because the extension activated depends on the opened filename extension.

You can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62275468/java-dependency-viewer-not-appearing-in-the-explorer-window-of-visual-studio-cod).

If it still does not work, could you provide the OS and the versions of the
VSCode and extensions?

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, you can try the following 2 steps:

1. open a `.java` file
2. reboot your vscode

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled quite a bit with this and none of the 'obvious' solutions worked.

The way I ended up solving the issue is by creating a new Java Project and looking at the difference in the config of the files.

Especially in the `.project` file, there were missing entries. Some also in the `.settings/*.prefs` files
After updating those in my own project, it got detected properly.

Answer (score 0):

As for the 3 dots, here's what I think: different versions may be slightly different, you see, there are no three points in this one [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrQqx.png). So you may update it when you are free.

As for the project view, you may have to open a project before it appears, Steven-MSFT has said it in detail, you can see it first. If you still have questions, you can provide some details again.

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Palette and type 'Explorer: Focus on Java Projects View' (can refer screenshot below)

hope it helps! :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, have you tried opening the Explorer box and checking the Java Project tag, I have the same problem and it takes a few hours to realize lol.

[image: Java project check box]

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that work for me was create a new visual studio code profile and try to install the extension again.

[create a new profile steps][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dphv6.png

I'm not sure that the order of extensions installation affect.